# Using point features to split lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, line, splitting

I have several point feature classes I would like to use to split a line feature class.  I am trying to determine whether there's a way to split the lines in the existing feature class (and not create a new one) using multiple different point FCs.

I am aware of the "Split Line at Point" tool, however this creates a new line FC each timeit's run, and as I have several point FCs I'd like to use I'll end up duplicating the lines into new FCs over and over.

I also thought maybe Identity might work, but that complains about Line not being a valid output for my input types.

How can I split, within an existing feature class, my lines using multiple point feature classes?

At this stage I'm considering copying all points into one temp feature class, splitting the lines on that (into a new FC) and then copying/replacing the existing lines with my new split ones.  Seems like quite a messy process just to split lines, but I haven't found anything quicker/easier yet.

Using ArcMap 10.8, and data is in file geodatabases

Comment: I can't think of any way to split in place nicely.  One alternative might be to create a copy of the line, and then delete one half from the original, and the other half from the copy.  That way it's all done 'in-place' (sort of), but that's probably even more tedious than what you're already doing.  At some point, you have to create new features for a split, either in another feature class, or in the original one...

Comment: If you want this to be repeatable, I would do it the way your doing it already, but within a tool that automates the whole process (either a script tool or a model builder tool).  Ie, spit to a temporary feature class, delete the original features, append from the temporary FC to the original FC, then delete the temporary feature class.